# Cannot edit word file from c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have created simple code to edit word file with the code below.
I used **Visual Studio 2015**, **Word 2007** and **office interop 12.0**

```
    private void inputdata_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTA.Text = getTA;
        lblPeriode.Text = getPeriode;
    }

    public void CariandGanti(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp, object CariKata, object GantiKata)
    {
        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildcards = false;
        object matchSoundsLike = false;
        object nmatchAllWordForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiacritics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;
        object matchPrefix = true;
        object matchSuffix = true;
        object matchPhrase = true;
        object ignoreSpace = true;
        object ignorePunct = true;

        WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute2007(ref CariKata, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
            ref matchWildcards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref nmatchAllWordForms,
            ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref GantiKata, ref replace,
            ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl,
            ref matchPrefix, ref matchSuffix, ref matchPhrase, ref ignoreSpace, ref ignorePunct);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //double totalKuantitasBarkon = Convert.ToDouble(txtSAKuaBarKon.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(txtMutTamKuaBarkon.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(txtMutKurKuaBarKon.Text);
        double totalMutasiBarkon = Convert.ToDouble(txtMutTamNiBarKon.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(txtMutKurniBarkon.Text);
        double totalNilaiBarkon = Convert.ToDouble(txtSANilBarKon.Text) + totalMutasiBarkon;
        //txtTotalnilaiKuaBarKon.Text = totalKuantitasBarkon.ToString();
        //txttotalNilaiBarKon.Text = totalNilaiBarkon.ToString();
        object missing = Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document aDoc = null;
        sPathSource = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\CaLBMN.docx";

        if (File.Exists((string)sPathSource))
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            object readOnly = false;
            object isVisible = true;
            oWord.Visible = true;
            aDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(sPathSource, ref missing,ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing
                , ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            aDoc.Activate();
            this.CariandGanti(oWord, "<117111SA>", txtSANilBarKon.Text);
            this.CariandGanti(oWord, "<117111Mu>", totalMutasiBarkon.ToString());
            this.CariandGanti(oWord, "<117111SAk>", totalNilaiBarkon.ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Tidak ada !!!");
            return;
        }
        releaseObject(oWord);
        releaseObject(aDoc);
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```

but after running, it display that 
An unhandled exception of type

> 'System.AccessViolationException'

occurred in `otomasiLapKeu.exe`

**Additional information**: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

[image: the warning]

can anyone help to fix this?

Sorry my english not to good.

Comment: I don't think 'ref CariKata' is the 1st thing to pass the Execute2007 function, its an object, shouldn't it be a string?